# How to avoid overwriting data file in newer app versions

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin studio to create an iOS app. I'm storing user information in a .dat file on the device. How do I keep this .dat file and it's information intact when I push a new update to my app over iTunes? Essentially when the user updates the app, I want the same user information they had before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your app will not overwrite any data stored in the Documents folder or any other writable folder.  The only way this will happen is if your app explicitly writes data to those folders.

Comment: So to confirm, this would apply to the Library folder as well? Right now I'm storing it in this folder because I read somewhere that the user is able to view the stuff in the documents folder in iTunes or something. It's not a big deal if this is the case but the file is stored as binary data so it wouldn't be much use for someone to read it.

Comment: The user can only see your app folders in iTunes if you enable file sharing in your app's info.plist.